# Error even after adding return statement in each condition

Tags: java, return

Added return statement for all combinations of if and else, still getting missing return statement error. Below is the code:

```
 public int searchInsert(int[] nums, int target) {
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        if(nums[i] <= target){
            if(nums[i] == target)
                return i;
            else
                return i+1;
        }
        else
            return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: what if `nums` is an empty array?

Comment: @Eran even after making it as for(int i=0;i<=nums.length;i++){, last else covers this case, still getting same error

Comment: Changing to <= is wrong. You should never enter the loop when the array is empty. Add a return statement after the loop.

Comment: Add a default return statement after the loop. The compiler believes that you can get to the end of the method without returning a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem confused. The code you pasted doesn't do anything. Specifically, because every path through the 'for' returns, this for loop is going to analyse nums[0], and that's all it'll ever do: if nums[0] is equal or higher than target, it returns 0, and if it is not, it returns 1.

javac can't compile this because your code doesn't say what should be returned if nums is empty. You've added returns that you shouldn't. Presumably what you want is to get rid of the last `else return i;` part, and add at the very bottom `return nums.length;` (which is the answer to the question: At what index should I insert, if the nums array is completely empty, or, ALL elements are higher than target?

Answer (score 1):

Both your return statements are within the if construct.  There is no return within the main block outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically, this might work but at the compile time, compiler expects a return statement outside for loop. Even it it’s “return null”, it’s fine.